# PHP - Regular Expressions with Double Quoted Strings

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, double-quotes

I'm trying to use regular expressions to extract a certain value from a string:

> "exec_hash": "/TPPE2ChB+5HuSHs84FBgx5/EgWi0OlaEXoXq4pq3Aukhc1Ypf0mZfKCJ10w=", "events_collector": "thiiM0ahsieSiech1phithe6chahngoo8sah6aid\n"

The data I want is the hash between the quotation marks. The problem is that there are multiple quotes within the string and `preg_match_all` function isn't returning the correct data. I've been playing around with regex for a while but can't figure it out. Ultimately, I'd like that data to be returned into a value. Ex: `$string1 = '/TPPE2ChB+5HuSHs84FBgx5/EgWi0OlaEXoXq4pq3Aukhc1Ypf0mZfKCJ10w=';`

Correction: I'm using curl to grab the page content. The data isn't stored in a variable.

$matches = array(); 
$thing = preg_match_all('/hash": "(.*?)", "events/',$page,$matches); print_r($matches);

It spits out a long array of much more than just the hash

Comment: How about showing us your regex pattern?

Comment: Any change that your string came from a json object? you string will always be in that format? Can you do something like this: http://www.tehplayground.com/#zPm65aO2r

Comment: $matches = array();
$thing = preg_match_all('/hash": "(.*?)", "events/',$page,$matches);
print_r($matches);

It spits out a long array of much more than just the hash

Answer (score 0):

Can you use substr?

haven't tested this, but in theory...

```
$pos_of_comma = strpos($str, ",");
if($pos_of_comma !== false) {
    $execHash = substr($str, 14, $pos_of_comma - 14);
}
```

Comment: Or you could also get the next position of the double quote after position 14, which is where the exec_hash string starts.

Comment: Can I use preg_match_all to capture everything between _hash": " & ", "events_collector?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's json_decodable:

```
//Get the result from curl request:
$curlResult = '"exec_hash": "/TPPE2ChB+5HuSHs84FBgx5/EgWi0OlaEXoXq4pq3Aukhc1Ypf0mZfKCJ10w=", "events_collector": "thiiM0ahsieSiech1phithe6chahngoo8sah6aid\n"';

//Parse the result:
$parsedResult = json_decode($curlResult, true);
//Get the hash:
$hash = $parsedResult["exec_hash"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will that work if the hash constantly changes every 24 hours?

Comment: Hi, what is very very important to validate this approach is making sure of what curl returns. If the content is guaranteed to be decodable with `json_decode`, and that the `exec_hash` key is guaranteed to be named like this all the time, then yes, this script will work all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions.

I figured it out. I missed the escape delimiters in the expression.

preg_match_all("/exec_hash\": \"(.*?)\", /",$page,$matches);